# Retain cycle with CCAction and CCCallFunc/CCCallBlock

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, retain

I'm in the final stages of releasing my first game, and after running Instruments:Leaks & Allocations, I see that I have a leak in my code caused by a retain cycle. I am using Cocos2d 2.0, and compiling my app with ARC, and I should mention that I started the project pre-ARC, and used the Xcode refactoring tool to convert it. My game has several animated objects per screen, each of which has a small number (1-7) of animated "variants" of that object (i.e. the barn opens to show a horse once and a zebra another time). I have a class that represents each animation, and another class for each variant. The variant creates a CCAnimation from a sequence of frames, and then creates an action which will be run whenever a touch event is received in the correct region. This action is what is causing my retain cycle. My declaration for the action ivar looks like this:

```
@interface AnimationVariant : NSObject
{
@private
    CCAction*  _action;
...
}
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CCAction* action;
...

-(void) setupActionWithMask:(int)mask
                     cycles:(int)cycles
                   hasScale:(bool)hasScale
                      scale:(float)scale
                masterScale:(float)master_scale
                  animationFrames:(NSArray*) frames
                   duration:(float)duration
                   andBlock:(VoidBlock)block;

@end
```

In the implementation of the setupActionWithMask method, I build up an NSMutableArray of CCActions, actionList. The sequence of CCActions varies depending on args, but usually it looks something like this:

```
[actionList addObject:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.0f scale:scale]];
[actionList addObject: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation] ];
[actionList addObject:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.0f scale:master_scale]];
[actionList addObject: [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:block]];
```

And I create the action like this:

```
_action = [CCSequence actionMutableArray:actionList];
```

The consuming class creates an AnimationVariant instance, sets its properties, calls setupActionWithMask, and passes in a block it wants executed when the action completes. When the consuming class wants to play the animation variant, it does so like this:

```
[self runAction: variant.action];
```

I tried declaring _action as:

```
CCAction* __unsafe_unretained _action;
```

which of course broke the retain cycle, but the action is destroyed, and is no longer around when it's needed (which is what you would expect, since __unsafe_unretained does not retain). I know __weak is the recommended solution, but as I am targeting iOS 4 and up, I don't think it's available to me.

I had another retain cycle in my code, exactly like this one, also caused by retaining (automatically with ARC of course) a CCSequence containing a CCCallFunc/CCCallBlock. I solved that one by just re-creating it whenever I needed it, which I could also do in this case, but these animations are triggered maybe a couple hundred times in the whole game, so I was hoping to follow the recommended Cocos2d Best Practices and retain the actions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retaining actions is not best practice. It's not even good practice. Though it comes heavily recommended by many, quite unfortunately.

Retaining actions works in many cases, but fails in others causing objects to leak. I'm guessing your case may be one of those.

Since you're targeting iOS 4 you can't use weak references. But you should probably reconsider unless you have to target the remaining few 1st and 2nd generation devices. Otherwise, google for iOS 5 adoption rate. The handful of devices that haven't been updated yet are well below a reasonable threshold, in particular if you consider that those users probably don't buy (many) apps (anymore) anyway.

Since you meantioned CCCallFunc, make sure you don't use them and replace with CCCallBlock. CCCallFunc are not safe to use with ARC, in particular whenever you have to __bridge_transfer cast a data object to void* (also bad practice).

There's always the chance that the necessary bridge cast back to the original object never occurs, and then ARC doesn't get the chance to clean up that object. With CCCallFunc this can happen when you run a call func action but the action is stopped before the callback selector is called, for example by changing scenes or stopping the action/sequence.

Cocos2D is also prone to retain cycles if you don't follow this rule:

- any node should only retain another node that is one of its children or grandchildren

In all other cases (ie node retains (grand)parent or sibling node) you must make sure to nil those references in the -(void) cleanup method. Doing so in -(void) dealloc is too late because the object will never get to dealloc when there's a retain cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had already come to the same conclusion and rewritten the code to not retain the actions at all, and can see no performance slowdown (not that I really expected to). I did not know about the -(void)cleanup methods - not sure how I missed that. But I did try to nil the ivar in dealloc, and as you said - by then it was too late. And I have already switched to blocks - but I also didn't realize CCCallFunc is unsafe with ARC - I just thought blocks were cleaner.

Comment: Actually you can't develop for 1st and 2nd generation devices (armv6 devices) on Xcode 4.5 at all. The minimum target version is 4.3.

Comment: @newacct - Yes I discovered this a couple days later when I went to buy a used 2nd Gen Touch for testing. But it does appear you can target 4.3, which still does not support weak references - unless I'm mistaken.